# How would ReactJS useState() be written if we are to write it ourselves using vanilla JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How would it actually be implemented?  If we are able to use

```
const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
```

and `count` is able to get `0` the first time but get the later state in later calls, if we have to implement `useState()` using vanilla JavaScript, how would that be done? The thing is `useState()` is not universal across all functions. In each function, it can have individual states even if function A and B are both using `useState(0)`.

I think the following will be quite close, although I don't know if it is almost equivalent:

```
function A() {
  printSomething('hi');
}

function B() {
  printSomething('hi');
}

A()  // => 'hi'
A()  // => 'I know you are calling me more than one time'
A()  // => 'I know you are calling me more than one time'
B()  // => 'hi'
B()  // => 'I know you are calling me more than one time'
```

Comment: React keeps track of hooks through the order they are called in at first render. This is also the reason why hook must always be called unconditionally and in the same order.

Comment: besides the "principle", I'd hope to actually to see how it is written in actual code

Comment: React is open source so go ahead look it up in the repo.

Comment: Too add to my first comment react also keeps track of which component is currently rendered. So it knows a) which component gets rendered and b) in which order the hooks are called. So when a component at a defined place in the tree renders and the third hook gets called it assumes this is the same hook that got called thrid at first render of that component.

Comment: https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/master/packages/react/src/ReactHooks.js#L78-L83

Comment: I guess https://unpkg.com/react@16.13.0/umd/react.development.js line 1581 will be easier to read... but it doesn't say a whole lot